# Set value based on row with the a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the data

```
    Mon, 02 Nov 2015    05:00
NULL    06:00
NULL    07:00
NULL    08:00
NULL    09:00
NULL    10:00
NULL    11:00
NULL    12:00
NULL    13:00
NULL    14:00
NULL    15:00
NULL    16:00
NULL    17:00
Tue, 03 Nov 2015    06:00
NULL    07:00
NULL    08:00
NULL    09:00
NULL    10:00
NULL    11:00
NULL    12:00
NULL    13:00
NULL    14:00
NULL    15:00
NULL    16:00
NULL    17:00
```

I would like to replace the NULL values with the value on Row 1 as date. The table contains this type of data for multiple dates. When the data for that specific date starts, it contains the date value after that the value is blank. The second column depicts the time of that day.

Please Help. Rajiv

Comment: So, are you looking to perform this when you are `INSERTING` or `UPDATING` the data.

Comment: Updation on the rows with NULL values.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have records with `null` for date, which should get the date of nov 2. But do you also have records with `null` which should get a different date? And if so, how do you tell which date?

Comment: Yes there are other rows which should get different date. Those dates for 3rd Nov, then 4th Nov and so on. When the row with the value date starts the time column begins for that day. After initial first row for that date till the time ends the date value is NULL. When the time value ends, another day starts and so on...

Comment: I'll ask again, how do you know which `null` values should get which date? In sql, tables are unsorted, so in order to find records belonging to the same date, you have to find a way to group/sort them together

Comment: @Rajiv okay, ignore my answer. I see you can have possible many dates under the `date` column.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: I am unable to group the data inorder to find the records for those dates. Unfortunately there is no identifier.

Comment: In that case it is not possible to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

The following may work. I don't have the tables to test it on and `SQLFiddle` is throwing errors (as in its having some interal issues). Have a try and report back:

```
UPDATE sample
  SET date =
    (SELECT TOP 1 b.date
     FROM sample AS b)
  FROM sample AS a
WHERE a.date IS NULL;
```

Basically, you are `SELECTING` the `date` field from the table, limiting to **only** 1 row (thus the first row only) and using that value to update the remaining rows where the `date` value is `NULL`

**EDIT:**

Just saw the OP update his Question. My code snippet suggestion will fail. As it will update ALL rows with the first occurrence of date. But OP has possible multiple dates in date column.

Comment: Do you have a set defined number of recorded time? ie `10 hourly records per day` or `only 10 records per day` Or is it also random. Or a definite end time of day? ie every day ends on `17:00`

Comment: unfortunately, nope :(

Comment: Any reason why your application/ solution can only insert the first occurrence of date but not for the remaining rows?

Comment: Actually I am pulling up a report from SSRS. The report groups it by default. I then ETL this info into a SQL Table.

Comment: Then, in effect are all the rows you pull from SSRS definitely sequential? It CAN be done if the date records are retrieved in ascending order. It won't be pretty though as you are basically relying on SRSS (which defies the purpose of SQL)